How can I output another string of text instead of only moving the cursor down?
I have just started learning C++, and have wrote this simple while loop program which is meant to ask the user to input their name until it has been given an input which isn't empty:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string Name;

    while(Name.empty()){
        std::cout << "\nEnter name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin>>std::ws, Name);
    }
    
    std::cout << "Hello, " << Name;
    return 0;
}

However, when the user gives the input an empty value into the variable, instead of printing another line of "Enter name: ", it just moves the cursor down another line within the terminal.
How can I get it where another line of "Enter name: " is outputted every time the while loop iterates?
I have tried to use \r and \n.

std::cin>>std::ws means "consume and discard all whitespace". This includes the line break. Only afterwards does getline start waiting for input.

std::getline(std::cin>>std::ws, Name); -- I'm curious as to why you did this, when you could have just done: std::getline(std::cin, Name);, which is probably what most C++ examples of using std::getline would show.

Why not simply std::cin >> Name?

@TimRoberts -- Yes, that too.  It is rare (at least to me) to see anything looking like what the OP was doing with std::getline.  Hopefully it isn't from doing cargo cult programming

just using std::cin, Name works. I just used the std::ws orginally because i thought it would it wouldn't matter if i used a method to prevent auto inputs in a different code file but I have noticed that it does now.

A basic solution to the problem would be to simply remove the >>std::ws part from your std::getline call. This makes it print the Enter name:  string after just pressing enter.
However, this would consider a name made purely of whitespaces to be valid, which you would have to check for. If you want to strip (trim) the string, there is this for some convenience functions.
If you want to just keep it simple, use a basic for loop.
Full code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

  std::string Name;
  bool is_whitespace = true;

  do {
    std::cout << "\nEnter name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, Name);

    for (int i = 0; i < Name.length(); i++) {
      const auto substring = Name.at(i);
      if (substring != ' ') {
        is_whitespace = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  } while (Name.empty() || is_whitespace);

  std::cout << "Hello, " << Name;
  return 0;
}

Hope I could help!

In this example, since Name.empty() and is_whitespace are both true before the 1st prompt is given, there is no need to evaluate them the 1st time, so a do..while loop would make more sense than a while loop.

Yea that is true. I still think this has some educational value, but I'm going to edit it really quickly. Thanks for the hint. Just out of curiousity, do you think compiler optimizations would catch this?

Note also, there are more whitespace characters than just ' '. Better to use std::iswspace() instead,and then replace the for loop with std::find_if() or std::ranges::find_if().

I know about stuff like \t that would also be considered whitespace, but when you really look at it, you would want to trim any whitespace from the end and the start of the string, but then again, this is sufficient to have educational value. Thank you for the note though
